# Angularjs rendering directive with transclude on body

Tags: angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I want to create a tooltip attribute directive with transclude, and render it on the body..

for example:

```
<div tooltip>
    <transcluded-content>content</transcluded-content>
</div>

module.directive('tooltip', function () {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: 'tooltip.html',
            transclude: {
                'transcluded-content': 'transcluded-content'
            }
        };
    });
```

I want to render the template on the body instead of the div...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have the element on the body, you could try moving it in the link function. How about this?

```
module.directive('tooltip', function () {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: 'tooltip.html',
            transclude: {
                'transcluded-content': 'transcluded-content'
            },
            link: function (scope, element) {
                angular.element('body').append(element);
            }
        };
    });
```

There are more complex approaches, but they'll require `$compile`-ing and other messy techniques.

Comment: But this way, all the element will be rendered twice (1. where the element is called, 2. in the body).. also, I want to know the messy techniques too, I want to learn...

Comment: `.append` should move the element, not clone it

Comment: There are many reading resources about the topic :) https://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/